# Page doesn't refresh after form is submited

Tags: php

I have a form submission via POST. I submit the form, and all is well, however if I try to reload the new page that the form goes to after submission, I get the "Do you want to resend data" message (FireFox). It might happen in other browsers too, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok, so what's the actual problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript reload after getting your data from form like this:

```
<script > window.location.reload(1);</script>
```

Or my suggestion for you is using AJAX for sending data and then reload page just like this:

```
    $("#form").submit(function(e) {
        var url = "yourURL"; 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $("#form").serialize(), 
            success: function(data){
                window.location.href = url; 
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#loader').show();
                $('#button').hide();
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
    });

        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
```

This snippet sends data to your url and after getting data successfully reloads page to your url that can be your existing url.

By doing this your browser does not display resend data alert.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand (correct me if I'm wrong) you are POSTing the form data to the same page as your form so when your refresh it asks if you want to resend the data.

This is a common feature in modern browsers allowing you to resend POST data to a page. You should prevent this so that people don't submit your form twice. You can achieve this by making a new page which you use to process the data and once it has processed redirect to the page you want.

`form.php --[POST DATA]--> process.php (redirect) ---> form.php`

This will send the user to the process page and process the form data and once complete redirect them back to the form page. On the users side they wont see the process page since its a redirect.